# How to set a page to display sub-categories and not products?

Tags: category, magento-1

How to set a page to display sub-categories and not products?

Answer (score 10):

To hide products from a category page, set the category's `Display Mode` to `Static block only`.

To list all subcategories, include the following bit of code in your `catalog/category/view.phtml`:

```
<ul>
<?php foreach ($this->getCurrentCategory()->getChildrenCategories() as $_subcat): ?>
    <li><a href="<?php echo $_subcat->getUrl() ?>"><?php echo Mage::helper('catalog/output')->categoryAttribute($_subcat, $_subcat->getName(), 'name') ?></a></li>
<?php endforeach ?>
</ul>
```

You may want to add checks for whether the subcategories are active, if there are any at all, and perhaps a flag of some sort to make the whole thing more flexible with a simple `Custom Layout Update`.